# how do I make SOLR find mistakes?

Tags: java, lucene, solr

I am looking for all document with "symptoms" in them.
I want the same or close results also for the following:

1. simptom
2. semptm
3. sympt

etc.
This is just an example to what I mean, I do not need a solution just for this specific word..
How do I define this in SOLR config files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't tried it myself, but it might be that the [PhoneticFilterFactory](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters#solr.PhoneticFilterFactory) can be of help. It generates phonetically similar tokens based on a provided token.

Comment: Do I need to download it, or it comes with the SOLR war?

Comment: It comes with the SOLR war, but you need to configure it in your schema.xml. It's an analyser which analyse text during indexing and/or querying.

Comment: I have added this class to the config. But queries for "Symptom" are success, while queries for "Simptom" bring zero results. Do I have to add it somewhere to the query analyzer too?

Comment: OK-FOUND IT, needed to add it to query analyzer AND index analyzer. Did the job :-)